# Node.js: JSON Parameter POST

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How do I write a JSON object with a parameter?

Thanks

Comment: could you provide more detail?

Comment: Not really. I need to POST a JSON object to a Sinatra server as a param. However, I don't know how to create it in order to be read in sinatra as [:param]. thansk

Comment: I think you have to put it in the `headers` of the HTTP.request. Go read up on the HTTP specification.

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't answering your question, you might want to clarify the question.

If you need to POST a JSON object to a server, you're best off using a library like jQuery.  Put your object in data and use the following.  (See also http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: I want to do that using Node.js